# how could i collect all the radio button that chosen in submit button?

Tags: asp.net

Here is my Code:

```
public partial class Play : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    int surveyId = 153;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // surveyId = int.Parse(Request[SurveyContext.SurveyID]);
        FillQuestion();

    }
    void FillQuestion()
    {
        IList<Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Entitis.Question> QuestionLst = Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Data.QuestionManager.GetQuestionBySurveyId(surveyId);
        try
        {
            RepPlay.DataSource = QuestionLst;
            RepPlay.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    protected void RepPlay_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList rblAnswers = ((RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblAnswers"));

        IList<Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Entitis.Answer> answerlst;
        answerlst = Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Data.AnswerManager.GetAnswerByQuestionID(((Eskadenia.Framework.Survey.Entitis.Question)(e.Item.DataItem)).ID);

        for (int i = 0; i < answerlst.Count; i++)
        {
            rblAnswers.Items.Add(new ListItem(answerlst[i].Name, answerlst[i].ID.ToString()));
        }

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("~/Surveys.aspx");
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Get selected radio buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you should databind the repeater only `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
       FillQuestion();
}
```

Otherwise all changes are lost and events aren't triggered.

According to the core issue how to get all selected ListItems in the repeater, is this helpful:

```
var allSelectedItems = RepPlay.Items.Cast<RepeaterItem>()
    .Select(ri => new{ 
         ItemIndex = ri.ItemIndex,
         SelectedItem = ((RadioButtonList) ri.FindControl("rblAnswers"))
            .Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .First(li => li.Selected)
    });
```

This presumes that you want the `ItemIndex` as identifier, if you need the ID you have to tell us where it's stored. You could also use `ri.FindControl("HiddenIDControl")` to get it.

Since you have commented that you want a dictionary, you could use this query:

```
 Dictionary<int, string> questionAnswers = RepPlay.Items.Cast<RepeaterItem>()
.ToDictionary(ri => ri.ItemIndex, ri => ((RadioButtonList)ri.FindControl("rblAnswers"))
        .Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .First(li => li.Selected).Value);
```

Here is the same without LINQ, you're right, in this case the loop is even simpler:

```
Dictionary<int, string> questionAnswers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepPlay.Items)
{ 
    string selectedValue = ((RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rblAnswers")).SelectedValue;
    questionAnswers.Add(item.ItemIndex, selectedValue);
}
```

I have noticed that my LINQ approaches were too complicated anyway, you can always use `RadioButtonList.SelectedValue` since a RadioButtonList doesn't support multi-selection.

Comment: i used a repeater here not a data grid so this  propartey is not exist in the repeater

Comment: @AhmadSadder: i have confused the repeater with a grid in my first version but it's already edited. Have you noticed that?

Comment: yes and thanks A lot ... but the compiler dose not accept ".Cast"

Comment: @AhmadSadder: that's a LINQ extension method (as the other methods like `Select`, `Where` or `SelectMany`). You need to use at least .NET 3.5  and add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class-file.

Comment: im really anoyying you.. but im new and my team leader told me to create a dictionary and for loop :(

Comment: @AhmadSadder: what is the key in the dictionary and what the value. Is the submit button outside of the repeater or in one item? Where is the key stored, can you show the relevant aspx code?

Comment: the key will be the Question ID and the Value will be the Answer_selected
the submit will be out side the repeater

Comment: @AhmadSadder: i have edit my answer to show some ways. Note that i have used `ItemIndex` since i didn't know where you store the ID. But i have mentioned ways how you can get it.

Comment: @  Tim Schmelter can you simplfy it to normal for loop :)

Comment: Give me a minute. **Edit** Done :)